# How to Solve "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds" With DataFrames of Varying Shapes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, index-error

I have checked the other posts about *IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds* but could not find solutions that explain my problem.

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
    Date    Balance
0   2020-01-07  168.51
1   2020-02-07  179.46
2   2020-03-07  212.15
3   2020-04-07  221.68
4   2020-05-07  292.23
5   2020-06-07  321.61
6   2020-07-07  332.27
7   2020-08-07  351.63
8   2020-09-07  372.26
```

My problem is I want to run a script that takes in a DataFrame like the one above and returns the balance of the each row using something like `df.iloc[2][1]`. However, the DataFrame can be anywhere from 1 to 12 rows in length. So if I call `df.iloc[8][1]` and the DataFrame is less than 9 rows in length then I get the **IndexError**.

If I want to return the balance for every row using `df.iloc[]`... how can I handle the index errors without using 12 different try and except statements?

Also the problem is simplified here and the DataFrame can get rather large so I want to try and stay away from looping **if possible**

Thanks!!

Comment: why to insert wrong row index? You know that your rows are between 0 and df.shape[0]-1

Comment: This is not a technical, but a content wise question. What should happen if dataframe is less than 4 rows long? If you really need to access 4th row, why would you even bother with smaller dataframes? You can solve it with only one try-except, checking only for length of dataframe greater or equal than 4.

Comment: `pandas` is based on columns names + index to localize data. This is an evolution of `numpy` which is a *bare* table. So while using `pandas` you should try to work with columns name and index. I guess you are perhaps trying to merge two dataframes. Take a look at the `merge` function ?

Answer (score -1):

My Solution was to use a loop over the length of the list and append the balance into a list. I then padded the list to the length of 12 with 'NaN' values.

```
num_months = len(df)
N=12

list_balance_months = []
for month in range(num_months):
    list_balance_months .append(df_cd.iloc[month][0])
list_balance_months += [np.nan] * (N - len(list_balance_months ))

balance_month_1, balance_month_2, balance_month_3, balance_month_4, balance_month_5, balance_month_6, balance_month_7, balance_month_8, balance_month_9, balance_month_10, balance_month_11, balance_month_12 = list_credit_months
```

with this solution, if `balance_month_11` is called and the DataFrame only has 4 months of data, instead of index error it will give np.nan (`nan`).

Please let me know if you can think of a simpler solution!